# Negative vega on IR swaptions mid curve

Tags: options, fixed-income

Why do IR bermudan options have negative vega on midcurve? Does it have something to do with mean reversion and a way of lower the price vs market prices?

Comment: do you mean negative vega across the whole ATM vol-grid, or just for specific expiry-tenor points? It'll be more useful if you can provide more details such as the call-periods of the Bermudan, versus the vega grid.

Comment: so say you are long 10nc2 berm. what would the vega profile look like? are you short vega anywhere? and how does mean reversion factor impact the berm price?